# How to apply a function with summation to all rows of one column

Tags: r

I would like to run the following [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4i5Xm.png) in R.

[image: 1]

My dataframe looks like this:

```
   Y   N       s
1 100  1       1
2 101  0.95    2
3 110  0.9025  3
4 112  0.8573  4
5 114  0.8145  5
6 120  0.7737  6
```

Where N is the term beta^s-1 in the formula and beta=1-0.05 (=discount factor).

The results of the formula should enter my dataframe in a new column. The first row of this new column can be calculated as follows with k=3

```
mydata$Ydsc<- crossprod(mydata$N[1:3],mydata$Y[2:4])/sum(mydata$N[1:3])
```

The second value for t=2 would result from

```
mydata$Ydsc<- crossprod(mydata$N[1:3],mydata$Y[3:5])/sum(mydata$N[1:3])
```

However, my problem is to properly formulate this in a function in R such that it is applied for every row in  column Y.

My approach was with the apply function, but I did not manage to incorporate the Y_t+s in my function:

```
fun <- function(x,y) {
  crossprod{x[1:3],y)/sum(x[1:3])
  x <- mydata$N
  y <- mydata$Y
}
Ydsc<-apply(mydata[,1],1,fun)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: can you fix `fun` it doesn't make any sense

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want this where `mydata` is defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.  `fun` takes a matrix `x` as input whose first column is `Y` and whose second is `N`.  It takes the the current row and successive rows of `Y` for a total of `k` rows and it takes the next row and successive rows of `N` for a total of `k` rows and normalizes those of `N`, multiplying and summing those.  It applies that to each row of the the input.

```
library(zoo)

k <- 3
k1 <- k+1
fun <- function(x) sum(prop.table(x[-k1, 2]) * x[-1, 1])
rollapply(mydata, k1, fun, by.column = FALSE, align = "left", fill = NA)
## [1] 107.4777 111.9316 115.1972       NA       NA       NA
```

At the expense of slightly longer code we could write `fun` like this for clarity:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  Y <- x[, 1]
  N <- x[, 2]
  sum(prop.table(N[-k1]) * Y[-1])
}
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "   Y   N       s
1 100  1       1
2 101  0.95    2
3 110  0.9025  3
4 112  0.8573  4
5 114  0.8145  5
6 120  0.7737  6"
mydata <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you for this precise answer!